# I am wondering if its possible to make a two way radio with Raspberry Pi

Tags: communication

Is it possible to create a two way radio that transmits and receives with a mic and speaker and one button to send with a Raspberry Pi? Like a intercom box that works over two way radio frequency so I could pick up a two way radio and talk to a Pi.

Answer (score 0):

There's no microphone input, but the kernel supports USB microphones.  Those are supposedly standardized, but you might want to google around before you buy one, or get it somewhere that will take it back easily if it does not work.

WRT to the radio, the GPIO pins can apparently be used to [transmit](http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter), so you then just need a receiver to hook up to it.

Comment: The problem is that the other Pi cannot receive FM. Its easy to send it using GPIO. So it will require a proper FM addon ontop of the Pi... at that point its cheaper to buy full FM walkie talkies instead.